# Implementing IValueConverter with BindableObject and the bound Property is always the default value

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to find a way to handle the fact that `CommandParameter` is not bindable with `IValueConverter`. Through reading I found a suggestion to Inherit from `BindableObject` while implementing `IValueConverter`.

When attempting to access the property, it is always 0, presumably taking the default value.

For reference, I am simplifying the problem by using the Xamarin.Forms **Shell** Template as an example:

When making the project use Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) and select Shell when creating the project. From there I made a small amount of modifications. Please note that I am merely setting a breakpoint to view what is assigned to the `BindableProperty`, which is always 0.

[image]

This example adds two properties to the already provided `Item.cs` class.

```cs
public class Item {
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    // Added these two properties. The idea is to Bind Number1 to the Text property of a label, and pass Number2 to the Property
    public int Number1 { get; set; }

    public int Number2 { get; set; }
}
```

In the constructor of `MockDataStore.cs` I added values for both `Number1` and `Number2` properties.

```cs
var mockItems = new List<Item>{
    new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "First item", Description="This is an item description.", Number1 = 5, Number2 = 20},
    new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Second item", Description="This is an item description.", Number1 = 2, Number2 = 8},
    new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Third item", Description="This is an item description.", Number1 = 3, Number2 = 6},
    new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Fourth item", Description="This is an item description.", Number1 = 4, Number2 = 7},
    new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Fifth item", Description="This is an item description.", Number1 = 1, Number2 = 10},
    new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Sixth item", Description="This is an item description.", Number1 = 8, Number2 = 2}
};
```

The Converter with BindableObject and IValueConverter

```cs
public class Number1Number2Converter : BindableObject, IValueConverter {
    public static readonly BindableProperty ValueProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Value), typeof(int), typeof(Number1Number2Converter), null);

    public int Value {
        get {
            return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }
        set {
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        // object value does have a value assigned, which is good however the bound Property of Value does not. This should have Number2 being passed in.
        var testing123 = Value;

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

On the line with `var testing123 = Value;` I placed a Breakpoint. I am not yet attempting to use `Value`, I just want to see it not being 0. Not one of the values I assigned Number2 in the MockDataStore is 0.

Here is the modified `ItemsPage.xaml`. Note the Label with Number1 bound and of course the Converter.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:App2.Converters;assembly=App2"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App2.Views.ItemsPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Clicked="AddItem_Clicked" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HasUnevenRows="true"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <d:ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>First Item</x:String>
                    <x:String>Second Item</x:String>
                    <x:String>Third Item</x:String>
                    <x:String>Forth Item</x:String>
                    <x:String>Fifth Item</x:String>
                    <x:String>Sixth Item</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </d:ListView.ItemsSource>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                d:Text="{Binding .}"
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                                FontSize="16" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                d:Text="Item description"
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="13" />
                            <Label>
                                <Label.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="Number1">
                                        <Binding.Converter>
                                            <converters:Number1Number2Converter Value="{Binding Path=Number2}" />
                                        </Binding.Converter>
                                    </Binding>
                                </Label.Text>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

`Value` is always 0 in this example. The parameter `object value` is assigned the int value of Number1, but the bindable property of `Value` should be assigned Number2. Is this concept fundamentally flawed or am I on the right track but failed at implementing something?

Comment: To be honest, the best approach is actually to *not* try to databind the command parameter. If your goal is only to manipulate two numbers that already are in your ViewModel, why not add a property to your ViewModel that can do what you're trying to add in your converter ? And then call a RaisePropertyChanged on this property whenever Number1 or Number2 properties change ?

Comment: The issue in this case is that the Item Model itself would require the extra property, not the ViewModel. There were arguments that adding a property to your model to facilitate this was not a good approach. I am open to different approaches of course but this was a suggested alternative, and now I am trying to understand why it's not working.

Comment: What I usually do in these cases is wrap your model inside a model ViewModel. Lots of plumbing, but should work

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong please, but it already is. This particular issue is because the ListView is bound to the Model, where the entire View is bound to the ViewModel. I could add another property to the Model mind you.

Comment: No it's not. What I meant is, that you can create a new class "ItemViewModel" that will wrap an Item object. In your view's viewmodel, create a list of ItemViewModel from your previous list of Items, and databind your ListView to this list of ItemViewModel. Then Inside your ItemViewModel you can add whatever properties you'd like to make your life easier, and it prevents you from doing any modification to your Item class

Comment: Oh ok I see what you are saying. `ItemsViewModel` > `IEnumerable<ItemViewModel>` > `Item`

Comment: Yes. Except that you probably don't want your ItemViewModel to inherit from Item, because ItemViewModel is gonna need the capabilities of a BindableObject. So ItemViewModel is going to inherit from the BindableObject type, and then expose the Item object via a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to send the whole Item object to your converter:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource Number1Number2Converter}}" />
```

Then, in your converter you should have access to both properties:

```
public class Number1Number2Converter : IValueConverter {    
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (value is Item item)
        {
             var number1 = item.Number1;
             var number2 = item.Number2,
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll clarify in my question above as well, but the `object value` having an `int` assigned is not in question, it's the `Value` Property that is the issue. I tried your chances anyway and Value is still always 0.

Comment: The MockDataStore provided in the template returns IEnunerable<Item> asynchronously.

Comment: You have a few syntax issues but your idea does work. For the sake of argument, what if I had multiple Labels each using a converter similar to this requiring the same technique? Would passing the model several times have a negative performance impact?

Comment: I fixed the typos, sorry I did it quickly directly on SO, should have done it in VS. No performance issues, you are just passing a reference around ;-) I think it is better than binding to a lot of properties.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same and got it working by setting the source of the binding to a parent element in the `DataTemplate`. Give a name to the StackLayout and set the binding source and path of the `Value` property.

```
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout x:Name="ItemLayout">
                    <Label>
                        <Label.Text>
                            <Binding Path="Number1">
                                <Binding.Converter>
                                    <converters:Number1Number2Converter Value="{Binding Path=BindingContext.Number2, Source={x:Reference ItemLayout}}" />
                                </Binding.Converter>
                            </Binding>
                        </Label.Text>
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
```

The bindable property Value of the converter is set and can be used to evaluate both numbers.

Comment: This is the only answer I found that somewhat works. I say somewhat, because the binding of the parameter is executed before the Convert method is called if you create the converter as shown here (inside the binding) but only after the Convert method (which is too late) if you create the converter as a resource.